# regex expression with optional parts

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression for this text:

```
 12.34  , 56.78  , "string one"  , "string two"
```

Here is my regex:

```
\s+(\d+).(\d+)\s+,\s+(\d+).(\d+)\s+,\s+(".*?")\s+,\s+(".*?")
```

Now I want to complicate the decoding: the strings can be present or not.
Examples:

```
12.34,56.78
12.34,56.78,"string one"
12.34,56.78,"","string two"
```

How can I modify my regex ?

Comment: @stribizhey: why did you delete your answer ?

Comment: I added it, in fact :) I deleted my comment because I used wrongly formatted input data.

Comment: Two propositions: how to choose ... schlomo added parentheses, used another method for the string. I am looking for the most evolutive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional non-capturing groups to make parts of your pattern optional:

Here is the updated regex:

```
\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)\s*(?:,\s*(".*?"))?(?:\s*,\s*(".*?"))?
                                     ^^^           ^^^^^               ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD8jH2/2)

Comment: Did you try [Txt2re](http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3?s=hello&1)? :) Maybe not exactly that, but free :) However, this sounds unrelated to the question.

Comment: Yes, I used it but I didn't find the method for the optional sub-expressions. Ideally, enter <spaces><real><spaces>"," etc ... and the result a regex

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
(\s*(\d+\.\d+|"[^"]*")\s*,\s*)*(\s*(\d+\.\d+|"[^"]*")\s*)
```

- The first part `(\s*(\d+\.\d+|"[^"]*")\s*,\s*)*` is for matching terms which end with a comma.
- The last part `(\s*(\d+\.\d+|"[^"]*")\s*)` matches the last element (no comma).
- The `|` in the middle is alteration, meaning match either the digit format, or the string format.
- `"[^"]*"` means first match a quote, then match any number of characters that isn't a quote, then match another quote (your string format).

See https://regex101.com/r/jS4sX9/1